# Javascript underscore - sort by sum of fields in array's object

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I would like to sort objects in array by the sum of fields of these objects.

Example:

```
var array = [
  {id: 1, T: 3, G: 3, K: 3},
  {id: 2, T: 5, G: 5, K: 5},
  {id: 3, T: 4, G: 4, K: 4}
];
```

How can I sort these objects by the sum of T, G, K? Thanks

Comment: How did you try do accomplish this?

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort`

Comment: Okay guys, I did it. `_.sortBy(array, function(array) { return array.T+array.G+array.K; })`

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys, I did it.

```
var array = [
  {id: 1, T: 3, G: 3, K: 3},
  {id: 2, T: 5, G: 5, K: 5},
  {id: 3, T: 4, G: 4, K: 4}
];

var sortedArray = _.sortBy(array, function(array) {
  return array.T + array.G + array.K;
});
```

Forgive me for that question. I think I deserved for all the minuses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compare function passed in sort function for array to achieve the result you want.

Sample Code: [codepen example link](http://codepen.io/sujeetkrjaiswal/pen/KVBzLR)

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, T: 3, G: 3, K: 3},
  {id: 2, T: 5, G: 5, K: 5},
  {id: 3, T: 4, G: 4, K: 4}
];

function sortData(){
  data.sort(function(a,b){
    return ((a.T+a.G+a.K)-(b.T+b.G+b.K))
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help but I have to do it by using underscore.